# What is the significance of System.CLSCompliantAttribute?

Tags: .net

I have gone through this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute.aspx and would like to understand its real significance.

When should you make this false?

Also, what are the pitfalls of not marking it explicitly?

I am mainly asking this question because of the design warning which you can read here...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182156.aspx

I want to understand, how can "not marking a library complaint" negatively impact me in any way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# supports some features that are not CLS compliant, including pointers, unsigned numeric types, public names that only differ by case, and others.

Public members exposing such features must not be `[CLSCompliant(true)]`.

Comment: VB.Net also supports some of those features, such as unsigned numeric types.

Comment: None, really.  Some .Net languages may only allow you to use explicitly CLS-compliant assemblies (I don't know of any).

Comment: Thanks SLaks. I have edited my question to be more clear. Why is this considered a Design Warning? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182156.aspx. Looks like it is just good to have thing.

Comment: I was never quite sure about that warning.

Comment: CLS is the minimal set of features that should be supported by any .NET based languanges (whether they come from Microsoft), so that if your API is CLS compliant, you can expect it is useful for other languages. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx If you don't mark them explicitly, other languages' compiler may generate an error (evidence needed).